# Use email address as username

Tags: users

Is there a specific or preferred way to set the username for new user registrations to be their email address?

At the moment my user signup form contains both fields:

```
<!-- Username -->
  <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="joesmith" {%- if account is defined %} value="{{ account.username }}"{% endif -%}/>
    {% if account is defined %}
        {{ _self.errorList(account.getErrors('username')) }}
    {% endif %}

<!-- Email -->
  <label for="email" >Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" {%- if account is defined %} value="{{ account.email }}"{% endif -%}/ autocapitalize=off autocorrect=off>
    {% if account is defined %}
        {{ _self.errorList(account.getErrors('email')) }}
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the conveniently named [`useEmailAsUsername`](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#useemailasusername) config setting.

When that is set to true, any new user that is saved with a valid email address will have that copied over to the username field as well.

Comment: Now all you need to do is mark it as the answer. :P

Comment: This made me weep with joy. So convenient and smoothly implemented.

Comment: This is just what I needed. It would be nice if it was documented on the User registration form page in the docs. https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/user-registration-form.html

Comment: Added a note to that page @TimPrint.